# Want to get output of detected color but it is looping for every frame. want to know how can get the output with detected color instead of frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm successfully detecting the color but unable to get the output of detected color just because it is giving the output per frame not per object so hoping to get any idea to get output by detection not by frames

## importing modules

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

## capturing video through webcam

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (1):
    _, img = cap.read()
# converting frame(img i.e BGR) to HSV (hue-saturation-value)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# definig the range of red color
red_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint8)
red_upper = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)


# finding the range of red,blue and yellow color in the image
red = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)


# Morphological transformation, Dilation
kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")

red = cv2.dilate(red, kernal)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=red)


# Tracking the Red Color
(contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(red, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)



for contour in (contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if (area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "RED color", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255))


        print("RED Detected")






cv2.imshow("Color Tracking", img)

# cv2.imshow("red",res)
if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

"I expect the output to be Red Detected only once when red color is actually detected but it is giving me Red Detected on every frame."

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put if statement, like:

```
int count = 0;

if(count < contours.size()) {
  print("RED Detected");
  count++;
}
if(count > contours.size()) {
  print("RED Left the frame");
  count--;
}
```

Sorry, only know c++.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I already tried it but for some reason it is not working. it is giving me the same output. Its ok if i get solution in any language I will convert it. Thanks

Comment: Did you put bool red_detected text = true; outside while loop? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But if i give red_detected text = true outside the while loop, it will only give output for first detection. And if i bring second object in-front of camera it will not give output at all.

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to understand is- whether it is even possible to get output only when the object enters in frame? and the output should not change until other object enters. Thank you

Comment: I don't read python well, but are you creating bounding boxes around contours of objects that are red? If so, think you can do something like my updated comment. For each detected bounding box, write "RED Detected". Not sure, I am also a beginner.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating boxes. But this will also not work because the contour starts with some high number and it is related to the size and shape of object. Thanks a-lot for your thought full help. But it is something to do with the frames as I'm also new in this so I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: if you get any other idea please let me know